# Does Nativescript app have issue on iOS 14?

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, ios14

After updating xcode and NS7 my app does not open on devices (simulator, ipad, iphone) ... after tns clean and ns run ios NOW I AM GETTING THIS :( I have no idea from where this NS-cloud came !

**MacMini:MY-DOC timmrichter$ tns clean
Error while loading nativescript-cloud is: Cannot find module '/Users/timmrichter/.local/share/.nativescript-cli/extensions/node_modules/nativescript-cloud'
(node:900) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
:heavy_check_mark: Cleaned directory hooks
:heavy_check_mark: Cleaned directory platforms
:heavy_check_mark: Cleaned directory node_modules
:heavy_check_mark: Cleaned file package-lock.json
:heavy_check_mark: Project successfully cleaned.
MacMini:MY-DOC timmrichter$ ns run ios
Error while loading nativescript-cloud is: Cannot find module '/Users/timmrichter/.local/share/.nativescript-cli/extensions/node_modules/nativescript-cloud'
(node:929) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Searching for devices...**

At the end app installed on device but simply does not open

```
                                                                                                                                                                 **Installing on device 7BE6C620-A73C-42DF-81AD-65A0083CB13E...
```

Successfully installed on device with identifier '7BE6C620-A73C-42DF-81AD-65A0083CB13E'.
Successfully transferred all files on device 7BE6C620-A73C-42DF-81AD-65A0083CB13E.
Restarting application on device 7BE6C620-A73C-42DF-81AD-65A0083CB13E...
CONSOLE INFO: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
NativeScript discarding uncaught JS exception!**

Comment: what is your output of running "ns doctor"?

Comment: @Yong Here it its: 
No issues were detected.

✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 7.0.10 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/core has 7.0.10 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/ios has 7.0.1 version and is up to date.
✖ Component @nativescript/android is not installed.

Comment: NativeScript debugger was not able to get inspector socket port on device 7BE6C620-A73C-42DF-81AD-65A0083CB13E 
Device socket port cannot be found.
Error while connecting to the debug socket. Error is: Error: Device socket port cannot be found.

Comment: It looks like that ns cannot get your local xcode. it will show "Xcode is installed and is configured properly." Do you have "xcode-select"?

Comment: @Yong xcode is installed ... but how do I know if I have "xcode-select"?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. Also, my app copies to the simulator then crashes upon the splash screen. I get the same type of messages you are getting. I have had my app run properly for a couple of years until ios 14 came out.

Comment: try "xcode-select --install" to install the command line developer tools

Comment: Im having the same problem, running on simulator works fine but running on real device stuck at  Successfully installed on device with identifier xxx

Comment: @bradrice have you updated to NS7? let us know here if you get any solution ..I am still tryng to fix it

Comment: I tried both ns7 and then rolled back to ns65 and for both, I get the crash immediately upon the splash screen opening. It's really hard to debug because it happens on launch so there is nothing to log trace.

Comment: Are you using any Nativescript-UI plugins? I'm using "nativescript-ui-listview": "7.1.0",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "7.0.2",

Comment: I found scss is causing my app to crash. When I switch to css it doesn’t crash. There may be something else, too, but that’s where I am at so far.

Comment: @bradrice I have updated both them to **"nativescript-ui-listview": "^9.0.2",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^9.0.3",**. How did you swith to CSS? from Webpack.config.js ? **resolve: {
            extensions: [".js", ".scss", ".css"],
            // Resolve {N} system modules from @nativescript/core**

Comment: I spin up a new app. It used app.css. It launched fine. When i changed to used app.scss the app started crashing after startup. I did get a log trace, so this may or may not be the issue. I’ll continue to work on this today.

Comment: OK, it wasn't scss after all. I had to upgrade to Nativescript 7.0.10. After that I was getting log messages which allowed me to debug. I had to update module paths and after getting them all resolved, the app stopped crashing. Now I have to figure out how to use the side-drawer, because it isn't working the way I was using it.

Comment: @bradrice How did you update module paths?

Comment: Instead of nativescript-angular/router use @nativescript/angular and instead of tns-core-modules/ui/page/page @nativescript/core etc. It took me a long time to work through all the changes migrating from 6 to 7 required.

Comment: @bradrice My app is running on NS 6.5.3 as I have some plugins like i18n which seems not supported on latest NS version. At the end I have downgraded to 6.5.3 and now it seems ok on xcode 12

Comment: How did you downgrade? Do you still run ns cli 7?

Comment: @bradrice ... I have uninstalled NS 7 and then installed 6.5.3... I am running with tns (no ns/cli 7)